# Blank space on top and bottom of iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm putting together a site for my friend's business and the home page consists of images and an iframe, but there's a blank space above and below the iframe. I've tried every trick I could find, but still no luck. Screencap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBoZs.jpg

The HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<div id="center">
<head>
    <title>Inali Grimalkin Sewing and Parties</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel=stylesheet href=css/styles.css>
    <meta name=description value="Inali Grimalkin specializes in cosplay, plushies, clothing, and anything that can be made out of fabric.">
    <meta name=keywords value="cosplay, clothing, fabric, sewing, parties, princess, plushies, anime, fandom, conventions">
</head>

<body>

<img src="images/bkg1.jpg" /><a href="shop.html"><img src="images/bkg2.jpg" /></a><a href="gallery.html"><img src="images/bkg3.jpg" /></a><a href="contact.html"><img src="images/bkg4.jpg" /></a>
<img src="images/bkg5.jpg" /><iframe src="indexcontent.html" width="516" height="307" seamless></iframe>

</body>
</div>
</html>
```

The css for the images and the centering div included above:

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

#center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 998px;
    height: 366px;
    margin-left: -499px;
    margin-top: -183px;
    }
```

The page the iframe links, indexcontent.html, contains a div id:

```
#content {
    background: url('../images/bkg6.jpg') fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
```

How can I get the iframe to sit flush against the images above it? The blank space below the iframe isn't an issue as there's no image below it, but the one on top interrupts the layout. This occurs in both Chrome and Firefox, and in Firefox the iframe winds up below the images instead of next to them.

Comment: Can you set width and height as 100% for iframe and padding as -10px;

Comment: Setting width and height as 100% broke the formatting, but adding `margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: -10px;` to the content div fixed it! Thank you!